# regsvr32 fails for simple freepascal COM dll

Tags: dll, com, freepascal, regsvr32

I'm completely new to free-pascal and I try to implement a simple dll that should register a COM class.
Unfortunately I could only find little information about [COM Programming for freepascal](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Windows_Programming_Tips#COM_Programming). Thus I hope that someone here can give me some hints or even a link to some examples.

So here is what I did:

- my operating system is Windows 7 64 bit
- downloaded and installed Lazarus 32bit version

  - Version #: 1.2.6
  - Date: 2014-10-11
  - FPC: Version 2.6.4
  - SVN Revision: 46529
  - i386-win32-win32/win64
- installed the ActiveX package in Lazarus
- made a new project - type `Library` with a simple `TAutoObject` and a default `TAutoObjectFactory` for the COM registration: source code included after this description
- build the dll
- use `regsvr32.exe` to register my dll --> this fails with

> "make sure the binary is stored at the specified path ..."
>   Invalid access to memory location.
>
> then I tried to change the default project options:
>   under *Compiler Options* - *Config and Target*, I set
>
> - *Target OS*: *Win32*
> - *Target CPU family*: *i386*
>
> still the same error occurs
>
> Project source

```
library LazarusSimpleComRegTest;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  Classes,
  { you can add units after this }
  ComServ, MyComObj;

exports
  DllGetClassObject,
  DllCanUnloadNow,
  DllRegisterServer,
  DllUnregisterServer;

end.
```

`MyComObj` Unit:

```
unit MyComObj;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, ComObj;

const
  CLASS_Plugin: TGUID = '{5E020FB0-B593-4ADF-9288-801C2FD432CF}';

type
  TPlugin = class(TAutoObject)

  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;

initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TPlugin, CLASS_Plugin,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);

end.
```

Comment: Did you run the command prompt with admin rights ?

Comment: yes - I have admin rights

Comment: You declared the 4 required COM server exports but you didn't write them.  It isn't automagic.  Google "freepascal dllregisterserver" to find example code, [like this](https://github.com/alrieckert/freepascal/blob/master/packages/winunits-base/src/comserv.pp).

Comment: those methods are implemented in ComServ which I include in my uses-list (I'm not sure if `ComServ` is part of the standard free-pascal or or the ActiveX package) - so they should be exported, right?

Comment: alos: if the functions did not exist, I could not even build the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem was, that I did not include the type library as a resource in my dll file: Now it works fine.

I've made a very basic and simple working example on git-hub with some basic documentation:
[lazarus-com-example](https://github.com/MartinTrummer/lazarus-com-example)